# Is there a way to generate a mat-tree from a Database?

Tags: angular, database, angular-material

I am currently working on a project using angular and Spring frameworks. I need to generate a nested Tree (mat-tree from Angular Material) from my database, and not from a static json table in the component.
I know how to get the data I want, but I can't figure out how to use it in order to generate the tree.

I used this angular material example https://stackblitz.com/angular/bevqmbljkrg, and I would like to use my Database data instead of TREE_DATA. 
Any help would be much appreciated!

[The data I get (with a service function) is in this format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1kjV.png)

but I only need to display "name" and "description"

The thing is that i will use this tree as a filter for different scenarios (using checkboxes as well). The structure should be like this:

**Scenarios**
 Description
 - description1
 - description2
 - description3

Name
 - name1
 - name2
 - name3

Comment: are scenarioTags the children in your case? if we take only the name and the description, then you don't need a tree to represent this data, you simply need a list!

Comment: no, scenario_tag is not a children. I editd the question so that it is more clear @FurqanS.Mahmoud

Comment: Okay, I'm writing it for you now

Comment: please find the updated answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The first step** is that You need to write a back-end function or (API), that back-end function should return the data in the same structure (hierarchy) shown in the `TREE_DATA`, let me say that each node in the tree is `elem` object, each `elem` object has properties `id, name, children:Item[]`

The function must return an array of items `Item[]`. 
So Function  prototype is:

```
<Item[]> getMyTreeData(){
  // 1- Fetch the tree data from the DB.
  // 2- Convert your data to the appropirate structure accepted by angular material
  // 3- return the data

}

    // I wrote the algorithm to convert your data in typescript, you need to use the syntax of your backend programming langauge
    // you should be fine with that

    let tree_data: any = []; // this will be array of objects 
    // collect all the descriptions and names nodes form the data array
    let descrptions: any = [];
    let names:any = [];
    Scenarios.forEach(elem => {  // Scenarios are the data array you posted in yout question
        let description_node: any = {
            name: elem.description
        }
        descrptions.push(description_node);

        let name_node: any = {
            name: elem.name
        }
        names.push(name_node);
    });

    let root_obj: any = {
        name: 'Scenarios ',
        children: [
            { name: 'Description' , children: descrptions},
            { name: 'Name ' , children: names},
        ]
    };
tree_data.push(root_obj);

// then you need to convert the root_obj to JSON format according to your programing language  
// that's it..
// the result of printing the root_obj should be:
[
    {
        name: 'Scenarios',
        children: [
            { name: 'Description' , children: [
                {name: 'Description1'},
                {name: 'Description2'},
                {name: 'Description3'},
            ]},
            { name: 'Name' , children: [
                {name: 'Name1'},
                {name: 'Name2'},
                {name: 'Name3'},
            ]},
        ];
    }
]
```

**The Second Step** is to call the function (API) you wrote before in the Step1 from angular application using  `get` http request & service. you will find a lot of resource on this topic, below is only a sample code to help you get the idea:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {


  constructor() { }

  getTreeData(){
     return this.http.get(`your api url goes here`);
  }
}
```

**The Final Step** is to inject the service into **your** component and subscribe to the function you wrote in the previous step, just like this:

```
 constructor(public api: ApiService ) { // don't forget to import the ApiService into your component
  // subscribe to get the data
   this.api.getTreeData().subscribe(
     data => {
       this.dataSource.data = data; // after reaching to this poin, angular will render your data automaticly instead of the example data.
       }
    );
  }
```

sorry for not creating a demo, but that should work fine for you.
plus you can enhance the code & performance by using `angular resolvers` later if you wanted to.

please comment below if something is not clear.

Comment: Hi @Furqan, Thank you for your answer, I will try it today, Ill come back to you if I need clarifications

Comment: Hello again @furqan, I did what you suggested, but I don't know how to convert my data to the appropriate structure for the tree

Comment: @Sbcom you need to update your question and post the structure of your original data, so I can help you.

Comment: Thank you very much @furqan, just one question: the step-one function should be written in the back-end code (I use java with Spring) ? or in a service class in the front-end?

Comment: everything under step 1 can be written inside the back end. 
but yet it's better to let the back end return the raw data, and then in the front at the service, you can do that convert thing, it's up to you.

Comment: please mark the answer as correct after you finish implementing the code.

Comment: Ok, perfect. Thanks, I will mark it as soon as I'm done ;)

Comment: sorry, I mean that the "convert" code can be written in front or back. 
but the `getMyTreeData` should be at the backend for sure

Comment: Okay, I aws confused... I'll try this

Comment: Just to clarify,
getMyTreeData() is written in the backend, it fetches the data from DB and returns it as is.

Comment: the "convert" part can be written in front (service or component?)

Comment: getTreeData() is the frontend service function that returns the data from getMyTreeData

Comment: yes, the convert code better to be placed inside the service, you can do it using the merge operator, it also can be written in the component inside the subscribe part.

Comment: Okay, I'm done implementing it  within the subscribe, with some format modifications, it works just fine!! Thank you very much @furqan

Comment: I noticed that you were still new with angular, that's why I tried to keep the front end code as it is and playing and adjusting the back end data to go with that front end structure.

Comment: could you add a stackblitz? @Sbcom

Comment: would you please add a complete working code on  stackblitz? @FurqanS.Mahmoud